# how to remove the emails while uncheck the checkbox from text area using javascript , there are multiple emails generated dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to remove the emails while unchecking the checkbox from text area, there are multiple emails generated dynamically i can remove all the emails while unchecking the checkbox except the first one...
here is my code
contactsCheckbox is id of checkboxes
showList is id of te`enter code here`xtarea

```
var email = "";
    $(document).on('change', "#contactsCheckbox", function () {

        email = "";

        if (this.checked) {

            email = $(this).val().trim() + ";";
            $("#showList").val($("#showList").val() + email);
        }
        else {

            email = this.value;

            var strValAdded = $("#showList").val().toString();

            var rrr = strValAdded.indexOf(email.trim() + ";");

            if (strValAdded.indexOf(email.trim() + ";"))
                strValAdded = strValAdded.replace(email.trim() + ";", "");

            if (strValAdded.indexOf(email.trim()))
                strValAdded = strValAdded.replace(email.trim(), "");

            $("#showList").val(strValAdded);
        }


    });
stringbuilder.Append("<div class=\"checkbox\">");
                stringbuilder.Append("<label><input type =\"checkbox\" id=\"contactsCheckbox\" class=\"chk\" value=\"" + data.Email + "\">" + data.Email + "</label>");
                stringbuilder.Append("</div>");
```

Comment: what?? It's not clear what you wanna do and what the problem is.

Comment: _"contactsCheckbox is id of checkboxes"_ - they have all the same id? Please show the related html!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: yes id of all the checkboxes is same and html is dynamically generated from controller method

Comment: sample of html is added above

Answer (score 1):

So first, element IDs are supposed to be unique. It is not your issue but it is very bad practice and you should correct that anyway. It will cause you more headaches down the road if you do not learn that now.

Your real issue is that your "if" statements are triggering false when you get to a value with a zero index. It is interpreting the zero index as a boolean value check:

Change:
if (strValAdded.indexOf(email.trim() + ";"))

to

if (strValAdded.indexOf(email.trim() + ";") > -1)

Example attached and I put an alert cmd in there so you can more visibly see what is happening with the 0 index boolean check. I also changed your change trigger to look by class instead of ID because your are going to fix your html to no longer be invalid in the near future...hopefully.

```js
    $(document).on('change', ".chk", function () {
        if (this.checked) {

            email = $(this).val().trim() + ";";
            $("#showList").val($("#showList").val() + email);
        }
        else {

            email = this.value;
            var strValAdded = $("#showList").val().toString();
            var rrr = strValAdded.indexOf(email.trim() + ";");
            
            alert(Boolean(strValAdded.indexOf(email.trim() + ";")));
            if (strValAdded.indexOf(email.trim() + ";") > -1) {
                strValAdded = strValAdded.replace(email.trim() + ";", "");
            }
            if (strValAdded.indexOf(email.trim()) > -1){
             strValAdded = strValAdded.replace(email.trim(), "");
            }
            $("#showList").val(strValAdded);
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox">
<label><input type ="checkbox" id="contactsCheckbox" class="chk" value="whatever1@wherwever.com"> whatever1@wherwever.com</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
<label><input type ="checkbox" id="contactsCheckbox" class="chk" value="whatever2@wherwever.com"> whatever2@wherwever.com</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
<label><input type ="checkbox" id="contactsCheckbox" class="chk" value="whatever3@wherwever.com"> whatever3@wherwever.com</label>
</div>

<input type="text" name="lname" style="width: 100%"  id="showList" disabled >
```

Comment: thank you so much Travis Action, it works now. i am beginner of java script i will learn it with the passage of time...